# filter duplicate records bases on the condition if certain columns are null

Tags: sql, oracle

```
        | Name | Place | Grade |
  Row 1 | Smith| (null)| (null)|
  Row 2 | Kat  | Poland| 2     |
  Row 3 | Kat  | (null)| (null)|
```

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50oG8.png)

I would like to fetch only the first two rows, i.e., if Place and Grade exist for duplicate name, then fetch that row (Row 2), else fetch the row anyway (Row 1).

This is the sample final result of a very complex query that I need to filter out again.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using Analytic Functions:

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT name, place, grade
FROM   (
  SELECT name, place, grade,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY place, grade) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which, for the sample data (I've changed row 3 to have a non-null grade):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Name, Place, Grade ) AS
  SELECT 'Smith', NULL,     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kat',   'Poland', 2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kat',   NULL,     5    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | PLACE | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kat | Poland | 2 |
| Smith | *null* | *null* |

---

#### Using Aggregation:

If you use simple aggregation:

```sql
SELECT name,
       MAX(place) AS place,
       MAX(grade) AS grade
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name;
```

Then the output is:

| NAME | PLACE | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | *null* | *null* |
| Kat | Poland | 5 |

Which mixes the `place` from one row and the `grade` from a different row.

To fix that you need to use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK ...` with the aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT name,
       MAX(place) AS place,
       MAX(grade) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY place) AS grade
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name;
```

Which outputs:

| NAME | PLACE | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kat | Poland | 2 |
| Smith | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GXhkZGyt)